# dojo 1.8: create widget and startup upon dojo/on

Tags: dojo

Hi I am looking for tutorial based on Dojo 1.8.
What I am looking for is:- create and instantiate widget pragmatically after dojo  page fully loaded and parsed, triggered after dojo/on button. I am not sure of which tutorial in Dojo website, for me to learn.

Please advise. 
Thanks in advance.
 Clement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't one tutorial that fully answer all your question but the following will be helpful:

- [Dojo Events tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/events/) and [dojo/on reference](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/on.html)
- [dojo/ready reference](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/ready.html#dojo-ready)
- [dojo/parser reference](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/parser.html)

To capture both the full loading of the page and parsing you need to use a combination of [dojo/ready](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/ready.html#dojo-ready) and [dojo/parser](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/parser.html). (I'm assuming that the parsing you refer to is the dojo widget parser, rather than the standard browser parsing of HTML).

To run code after parsing you'll need to add **parseOnLoad: false** to your [dojoConfig](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/dojo_config/) and run the parser manually; otherwise, there is no way of capturing when it is complete.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="true">
    require([
        "dojo/ready",
        "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/on,
        "dojo/query"
    ], function(
        ready, parser, on, $
    ){
        ready(function(){
            // Only run after the page is fully loaded
            parser.parse().then(function(instances){
                // Only run after parser has parsed the page

                var myButton = $("#myButtonid");  // Find your button
                if(myButton.length > 0){ // Check button is found
                    on(myButton[0], "click", function(evt){

                        // ... add your code here to create and
                        //    instantiate widget 

                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Don't forget that you need to turn off automatic parsing of widgets in you [dojoConfig](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/dojo_config/), hence, something like this (in the head):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojoConfig= {
        "parseOnLoad": false,
        "async": true
        // ...other settings
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks... Hmm it's quite complex. I will try out. Would be helpful, if there's a tutorial. Thank again.

Comment: Yes, waiting for the Dojo parser to complete, adds another layer complexity.  If the button you are connecting to is not a Dojo widget (ie dijit/form/Button) then you can remove that step.  You could strip-out the parser.parse().then and just run the code in the dojo/ready function and turn parseOnLoad back on again.  this approach might work anyway as connecting to the button via dojo/on will continue to work after the button is transformed into a widget.  However, if your code is trying to get access to functionality of any page widgets you'll need the longer approach detailed above.